# Which variables are initialized when in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, variables, initialization, delphi-2009

So I always heard that class fields (heap based) were initialized, but stack based variables were not.  I also heard that record members (also being stack based) were also not initialized.  The compiler warns that local variables are not initialized ([DCC Warning] W1036 Variable 'x' might not have been initialized), but does not warn for record members.  So I decided to run a test.

I always get **0** from *Integers* and **false** from *Booleans* for all record members.

I tried turning various compiler options (debugging, optimizations, etc.) on and off, but there was no difference.  All my record members are being initialized.

What am I missing? I am on Delphi 2009 Update 2.

```
program TestInitialization;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TR = Record
  Public
    i1, i2, i3, i4, i5: Integer;
    a: array[0..10] of Integer;
    b1, b2, b3, b4, b5: Boolean;
    s: String;
  End;

var
  r: TR;
  x: Integer;

begin
  try
    WriteLn('Testing record. . . .');
    WriteLn('i1 ',R.i1);
    WriteLn('i2 ',R.i2);
    WriteLn('i3 ',R.i3);
    WriteLn('i4 ',R.i4);
    WriteLn('i5 ',R.i5);

    Writeln('S ',R.s);

    Writeln('Booleans: ', R.b1, ' ', R.b2, ' ', R.b3, ' ', R.b4, ' ', R.b5);

    Writeln('Array ');
    for x := 0 to 10 do
      Write(R.a[x], ' ');
    WriteLn;

    WriteLn('Done . . . .');
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

**Output:**

```
Testing record. . . .
i1 0
i2 0
i3 0
i4 0
i5 0
S
Booleans: FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Array
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Done . . . .
```

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132725/are-delphi-variables-initialized-with-a-value-by-default

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Global variables are zero-initialized. Variables used in the context of the main `begin`..`end` block of a program can be a special case; sometimes they are treated as local variables, particularly `for`-loop indexers. However, in your example, `r` is a global variable and allocated from the .bss section of the executable, which the Windows loader ensures is zero-filled.

Local variables are initialized as if they were passed to the `Initialize` routine. The `Initialize` routine uses runtime type-info (RTTI) to zero-out fields (recursively - if a field is of an array or record type) and arrays (recursively - if the element type is an array or a record) of a managed type, where a managed type is one of:

- AnsiString
- UnicodeString
- WideString
- an interface type (including method references)
- dynamic array type
- Variant

Allocations from the heap are not necessarily initialized; it depends on what mechanism was used to allocate memory. Allocations as part of instance object data are zero-filled by `TObject.InitInstance`. Allocations from `AllocMem` are zero-filled, while `GetMem` allocations are not zero-filled. Allocations from `New` are initialized as if they were passed to `Initialize`.

Comment: The important thing is remember that "initialized" <> "zero-filled". For example, initialized record with string and integer fields can be not zero-filled. Of course, the string field will be nil, but integer field can be <> 0.

Comment: Yes - Initialize initializes fields and array elements of managed types only.

Comment: anonymous methods should be added to the list I think

Answer (score 9):

> I always get 0 from Integers and false from Booleans for all record members.
>
> I tried turning various compiler options (debugging, optimizations, etc.) on and off, but there was no difference. All my record members are being initialized.
>
> What am I missing?

Well, apart from your test using global instead of local variables: the important thing that you are missing is the distinction between variables that ***coincidentally appear*** to be initialised, and variables that ***actally are*** initialised.
**BTW**: This is the reason programmers who don't check their warnings make the common mistake of assuming their poorly written code is behaving correctly when the few tests they do; happen to have 0 and False defaults.... `Want To Buy: random initialisation of local variables for debug builds.`

Consider the following variation on your test code:

```
program LocalVarInit;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

procedure DoTest;
var
  I, J, K, L, M, N: Integer;
  S: string;
begin
  Writeln('Test default values');
  Writeln('Numbers: ', I:10, J:10, K:10, L:10, M:10, N:10);
  Writeln('S: ', S);
  I := I + 1;
  J := J + 2;
  K := K + 3;
  L := L + 5;
  M := M + 8;
  N := N + 13;
  S := 'Hello';
  Writeln('Test modified values');
  Writeln('Numbers: ', I:10, J:10, K:10, L:10, M:10, N:10);
  Writeln('S: ', S);
  Writeln('');
  Writeln('');
end;

begin
  DoTest;
  DoTest;
  Readln;
end.
```

With the following sample output:

```
Test default values
Numbers:    4212344   1638280   4239640   4239632         0         0
S:
Test modified values
Numbers:    4212345   1638282   4239643   4239637         8        13 //Local vars on stack at end of first call to DoTest
S: Hello


Test default values
Numbers:    4212345   1638282   4239643   4239637         8        13 //And the values are still there on the next call
S:
Test modified values
Numbers:    4212346   1638284   4239646   4239642        16        26
S: Hello
```

**Notes**

- The example works best if you compile with optimisation off. Otherwise, if you have optimisation on:

  - Some local vars will be manipulated in CPU registers.
  - And if you view the CPU stack while stepping through the code you'll note for example that `I := I + 1` doesn't even modify the stack. So obviously the change cannot be carried through.
- You could experiment with different calling conventions to see how that affects things.
- You can also test the effect of setting the local vars to zero instead of incrementing them.
- This illustrates how you are entirely dependent on what found its way onto the stack *before* your method was called.

Comment: "programmers who don't check their warnings make the common mistake" - I read somewhere a tip for Delphi programmers and since then I made that tip my motto: "TREAT COMPILER HINTS AS WARNING AND THE WARNINGS AS ERRORS"!

Comment: @Altar I'd go a step further and follow a zero hints&warnings policy.  As soon as you start making any excuses to permit some hints, you create a possibility of missing new ones in amongst hundreds of old ones. Any hint/warning can very easily be fixed/avoided, but it takes a lot of boring work to fix hundreds of them.

Comment: @Altar Ok, now I get it... elevate all hints to warnings, and all warnings (including ex-hints) to errors. :) My first impression was that you would accept some hints.

Comment: Your post should be marked as Accepted Answer since it responds to the ACTUAL question: "why records SEEMS to be initialized"!

Comment: I think I will make "Want To Buy: random initialisation of local variables for debug builds" my logo :) :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation, and thought the same, but when I add other variables used before the record, the values become garbage, so before I use my record I had to initialize using

```
FillChar(MyRecord, SizeOf(MyRecord), #0)
```

Comment: I've heard that FillChar can cause troubles if your record contains previously allocated managed members (strings, etc.) or allocated object references, but for new records you are correct.

Comment: @Jim: Allen answered a question about that few days ago, he told the FillChar will not affect when it is used only for initialization, but after access a refcount member and then call fillchar, you will get a memory leak.

Comment: You can call `Finalize` on the record before the `FillChar`. That will make sure that all reference counted fields will be cleaned up first.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the example code you provided, the record is actually a global variable, so it will be completely initialized. If you move all that code to a function, it will be a local variable, and so, per the rules given by Barry Kelly, only its string field will be initialized (to '').