# What is the default value of 'Result' in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Is there any guaranteed default value for the *Result* variable of a function, like 0, '' or nil? Or should *Result* always be initialised before use?

I have a function returning a string like this:

```
function Foo(): String
begin
    while {...} do
    Result := Result + 'boingbumtschak';
end;
```

It worked fine, but now I get some strings containing contents from a previous call to the function. When I add a `Result := ''` at the beginning, it is OK. When should I initialize the `Result` variable and when don't I have to? (strings, primitives, Class instances (nil))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which variables are initialized when in Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861045/which-variables-are-initialized-when-in-delphi)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to setLength a dynamic array on initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314918/do-i-need-to-setlength-a-dynamic-array-on-initialization)

Comment: The single most ugly thing is that the compiler neither does complain about the unitialized result, nor is it treated and auto-initialized like an `out`. Instead, it is more kind of a `var` and hence gives you the ability (if we want to call it that way) to do Dumb Things™ with it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A function return value of type `string` is actually treated by the compiler as an implicit var parameter. When the function begins execution, the `Result` variable contains whatever is in the local variable to which the return value will subsequently be assigned.

Accordingly, you should always initialize function return values. This advice holds not only for strings, but for all data types.

This issue was discussed just yesterday here on Stack Overflow:

[Do I need to setLength a dynamic array on initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314918/)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers This seems to be the answer you are talking of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/861178/2932052

Answer (score 8):

> If the function exits without
>   assigning a value to Result or the
>   function name, then the function's
>   return value is **undefined**.

see [Delphi Reference](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Reference) > [Procedures and Functions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions) > [Function Declarations](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Function_Declarations)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what it's like in Delphi, but I *always* initialize variables to a sane value before I perform operations on them (even if that sane value is `null`, which it might very well be in some situations). Many times it's unneeded, but in those instances, I count on the compiler or JITter to optimize the assignment out if it wants to, rather than relying on potentially undocumented language semantics or compiler implementation details. Maybe it's my background in C, which in and of itself essentially guarantees nothing about initial values, but it feels worthwhile to spend the extra one line of code (at most) in order to get clearer code. By explicitly assigning a value before you start working on the variable, you establish a clear contract with whoever is reading the code; they can trust that their idea of what the starting value of the variable is, actually holds.

As for this particular question, though; isn't `Result` supposed to be function-local in scope? I would be very surprised if such a variable, even though special, kept values from previous invocations of the function.

Comment: Yes, it looks like I should be! Another reason to add to the list for my preference to always initialize variables before using them.

Comment: *always initialize variables* -- This is in general good style. But there are languages that provide implicit initialization, so there are chances that you write inefficient code, see for example (most) C++ classes with their constructors where you have a well-supported by-value option.