# Program freezing on generating random string

Tags: delphi

I am learning delphi on the german site delphi-treff.

they provide a function to generate random string.

https://www.delphi-treff.de/tipps-tricks/object-pascal/strings/zufallstring-generieren/

```
function RandomString(strlength: integer): string;
var
  temp : integer;
begin
  randomize;
  repeat
    temp := random(122); //ggf. erhöhen
    if temp in [48..57{0-1}, 65..90{A-Z}, 97..122{a-z}] then
    //Kann um beliebige ASCII-Zeichen erweitert werden,
    //ggf. den Wert in Random hochsetzen
      result := result + Chr(temp);
  until length(result) = strlength;
end;
```

as you can see here:

```
if temp in [48..57{0-1}, 65..90{A-Z}, 97..122{a-z}] then
```

they only put 0-1, A-Z and a-z as characters.

However I thought my program crashes because of this function.

so I changed:  until length(result) = strlength;

to:  until length(result) >= strlength;

and indeed it sometimes is > strlength.

Can someone explain why it is bigger?

It shouldn't be bigger because it only adds 1 character at a time?

Comment: `Result` is not initialized before the loop, hence the length overflow. `Randomize` should only be initialized once at program start.

Comment: @LURD so Result gets intialized with a random value that is longer than strlength and therefore will never meet the criteria?

Comment: See [What is the default value of 'Result' in Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336863/what-is-the-default-value-of-result-in-delphi).

Comment: thanks @LURD. I think i should write the admin as i spent some hours trying to figure out my program freezes. thanks again

Comment: Please also note that ordinals 48..57 stands for ASCII characters '0'..'9', (not '0'..'1') and that the result of the function never contains a 'z' (ordinal 122) because `function Random(const ARange: integer): integer` returns a number X which is `0 <= X < ARange`

Comment: It's also possible to have a problem if the function is called with `strlength <= 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Result` is treated as an implicit `var` parameter and must be initialized before use. See [What is the default value of 'Result' in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5336863/576719).

In this case an uninitialized `Result` parameter will cause the length overflow.

Another issue, `Randomize` should only be called once at program start.

Comment: Result is *never* uninitialized, but it doesn't have to be empty either.