# Initial value of OleVariant variable

Tags: delphi

I always was thinking that OleVariant variables always has initial value equal to Unassigned (type VT_EMPTY). But the following simple code compiled with XE3 shows me it is not true.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  ActiveX;

function GetValue: OleVariant;
begin
  Result := TVariantArg(Result).vt;
end;

function GetValue2: OleVariant;
begin
  Result := 10;
  Result := GetValue;
end;

var
  Msg: string;
begin
  Msg := GetValue2;
  Writeln(Msg);
end.
```

App writes "3". Is it normal?

Comment: A function Result variable has no guaranteed default value. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10084043/576719.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return value of a Delphi function, for types that don't fit in a register, are passed as var parameters. So the compiler transforms the code to be like so:

```
procedure GetValue(var Result: OleVariant);
```

Hence the value of `Result` on entry to the function is the value of the variable that you assign the return value to.

So your calling code is transformed to

```
function GetValue2: OleVariant;
begin
  Result := 10;
  GetValue(Result);
end;
```

So in its entirety your program becomes

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  ActiveX;

procedure GetValue(var Result: OleVariant);
begin
  Result := TVariantArg(Result).vt;
end;

procedure GetValue2(var Result: OleVariant);
begin
  Result := 10;
  GetValue(Result);
end;

var
  tmp: OleVariant;
  Msg: string;
begin
  GetValue2(tmp);
  Msg := tmp;
  Writeln(Msg);
end.
```

Which explains the output of `VT_I4`.

Of course this is all a consequence of implementation detail. You should always initialize function return values.

Comment: It is a shame that the compiler doesn't always treat the implicit output parameter as an `out` instead of a `var`.