# Variable 'xxx' might not have been initialized

Tags: delphi

I have a software where I have many errors like

> Variable 'xxx' might not have been initialized

the question is when a variable is uninitialized, does its will have a default value (exemple false for boolean) or it's get a completely random number ? ex :

```
function test: boolean;
begin
end;
```

what will be the result of test ? false? or a total random value ?
Other example:

```
function test: boolean;
var a: boolean;
begin
  if a then result := true
  else result := false;
end;
```

Same here, what will be the value of a?  false? or a total random value ?

Comment: If it doesn't compile, how can it have a "value"?

Comment: 1) Random. 2) Random. See also [Is function's result always initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5429480/576719) and [local variable initialized in delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27189030/576719)

Comment: Actually it is not necessarily random. It's whatever happens to be on the stack. Which could be repeatable. It's better to say that the value is undefined.

Comment: Note that the result of the first (empty) function "returning" a boolean could even be a boolean containing, say, 57 or 93 (or any other undefined byte value), instead of true or false.

Comment: Note also that `Boolean(57)` evaluates to true, while `Boolean(57) = TRUE` evaluates to false.