# Converting integer to floating point number in Delphi

Tags: pointers, delphi

Could someone please explain the below code to me? It takes the `Integer` and converts it to a `Single` floating point number but if someone could break this down and elaborate that would be helpful.

```
singleVar := PSingle(@intVar)^
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect "dangling pointers" if "Assigned()" can't do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598408/how-to-detect-dangling-pointers-if-assigned-cant-do-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't convert the integer to a float. It *reinterprets* the bytes of the 32-bit integer as a single (a floating point data type that also has 32 bits).

`@intVar` is the address of the integer data in memory. The type is pointer to integer (`PInteger`). By writing `PSingle(@intVar)`, you tell the compiler to pretend that it is a pointer to a single; in effect, you tell the compiler that it should interpret the data at this place in memory as a single. Finally, `PSingle(@intVar)^` is simply dereferencing the pointer. Hence, it is the "single" value at this location in memory, that is, the original bytes now [interpreted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) as a single.

Interpreting the bytes of an integer as a single doesn't give you the same numerical value in general. For instance, if the integer value is `123`, the bytes are `7B00 0000`. If you interpret this sequence of bytes as a single, you obtain `1,72359711111953E-43` which is not numerically equivalent.

To actually *convert* an integer to a single, you would write `singleVar := intVar`.