# Delphi and Nullable types

Tags: c#, delphi

I am converting some C# code to Delphi.

In  c#, I have Nullabe types as:

```
System.Nullable<T> variable
```

or

```
T? variable
```

Then, I can use something as:

```
int?[] arr = new int?[10];
```

Is there some Delphi VCL equivalent to it?

Comment: You could use a pointer in delphi.

Comment: Use a nullable type. For instance Spring has one. This would never be a VCL type anyway, it's RTL. Try a web search.

Comment: Did you get what @Wimmel meant about using a pointer?

Comment: @ David Heffernan: Thank you  for your reposne. I have a small portion of code using Nullable and to use Spring is much more I need for.

Comment: @MartynA: No, I did not.

Comment: Spring's nullable stands alone I think. In any case you can use the ideas there. Are you prepared to write code or do you want a library recommendation. Did you do any Web search?

Comment: There are lots of hits with a google search for *delphi nullable* that also include code. They nearly all work in the same way (with a record)

Comment: @David Heffernan, Yes I did.  I thought maybe there was a more simple solution. I'd  not like write many code. Then, I will look into Spring. Thank you.

Comment: You could try to use the nullable types in my dzlib: https://sourceforge.net/p/dzlib/code/HEAD/tree/dzlib/trunk/src/ (those units that start with u_dzNullable* ). Not sure whether that will solve your problem, because I am not familiar with C#'s nullable types.

Comment: [Nullable implementation from Allen Bauer's blog](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2008/09/18/38869)

Comment: @Dalija Prasnikar Thank you. I guess it is a good choice to start with.

Comment: Allen Bauer's 2008 Nullable blog post is currently at: [A “Nullable” Post](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/a-nullable-post/)

Answer (score 4):

I found [this](https://blog.therealoracleatdelphi.com/2008/09/a-post_18.html) interesting article about Nullable types and [this](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Nullable_types) simplified implementation:

```
unit Nullable;

{$mode delphi}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

type
  TNullable<T> = record
  private
    FHasValue: Boolean;
    FValue: T;
    function GetValue: T;
    procedure SetValue(AValue: T);
  public
    procedure Clear;
    property HasValue: Boolean read FHasValue;
    property Value: T read GetValue write SetValue;
    class operator Implicit(A: T): TNullable<T>;
    class operator Implicit(A: Pointer): TNullable<T>;
  end;

implementation

{ TNullable }

function TNullable<T>.GetValue: T;
begin
  if FHasValue then
     Result := FValue
  else
    raise Exception.Create('Variable has no value');
end;

procedure TNullable<T>.SetValue(AValue: T);
begin
  FValue := AValue;
  FHasValue := True;
end;

procedure TNullable<T>.Clear;
begin
  FHasValue := False;
end;

class operator TNullable<T>.Implicit(A: T): TNullable<T>;
begin
  Result.Value := A;
end;

class operator TNullable<T>.Implicit(A: Pointer): TNullable<T>;
begin
  if A = nil then Result.Clear
  else raise Exception.Create('Pointer value not allowed');
end;

end.
```

Comment: In my simple test, the `Value` or `HasValue` is not initialized, so I would recommend using something else (e.g. delphi-neon)

Comment: Aren't [objects fields always initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/132770/4528159)? I don't know which is the behavior for generics, but at least `FHasValue` should be initialized

Comment: procedure TForm1.FPTest;
var
  NS: TNullable<Integer>;
begin
  ShowMessage('HasValue: ' + BoolToStr(NS.HasValue, True));
  ShowMessage('Value: ' + NS.Value.ToString);
end;
Result: `True`, `Some large number`..
One would expect `HasValue` to be false, and therefore accessing NS.Value should throw an error.. That is what delphi-neon does

Comment: You're right, my fault. That's because `TNullable` is a record (and not an object), so it behave like a common base type (like `string`, `integer`...).  If you use it as a local variable, it is not automatically initialized. If you place it as a form's field, it will be automatically initialized instead