# What does 'cdecl = nil' (placed after a function declaration) mean?

Tags: delphi

Check this [demo source](https://github.com/MahdiSafsafi/delphi-detours-library/blob/master/v2/Demo/DetoursDemo/Delphi/RTL/Demo1/uMain.pas) from the excellent Detour library:

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var
  TrampolineGetMemory: function(Size: NativeInt): Pointer;
cdecl = nil;
```

Please look at the `cdecl = nil;` statement. What does it mean in this context?

Note - I already know that `cdecl` stands for a calling convention.

Comment: The same as `var i: Integer = 42;`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think that particular initialization, in some programs, can actually gain you about ten million years of perf increase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just another way to initialize the variable.  For example:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var
  i : integer = 5;
begin
  WriteLn(i);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

it may be clearer if it was written on one line as

```
var
  TrampolineGetMemory: function(Size: NativeInt): Pointer; cdecl = nil;
```

Or maybe even better if a type was defined :

```
type
  TTrampolineGetMemory = function(Size: NativeInt): Pointer; cdecl;

//... 
 var
   TrampolineGetMemory: TTrampolineGetMemory = nil;
```

Comment: Note that it completely redundant as global variables are initialised to `0/nil/false` anyway - see [Are delphi variables initialized with a value by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132725/are-delphi-variables-initialized-with-a-value-by-default). This is like initialising an event handler to nil or a boolean field to false in a constructor - completely pointless

Comment: @GerryColl Indeed it is.  Sometimes coding standards will dictate this sort of thing, though (I guess?).  Could be explicit for clarity, or possibly just a reflex carried over from locals.  It's not necessary, but I'm not sure I'd go so far as to call it wrong.

Comment: Seeing initialisation to 0 in a constructor is a code smell to me - it implies that the original coder either didn't understand Delphi, or couldn't be bothered to find out what the default is.

Comment: @Gerry or wanted the reader to be in no doubt and not have to think

Answer (score 7):

`TrampolineGetMemory` is a procedural **variable** initialized to `nil`.

It's easier to see if rewritten like

```
type
  TTrampolineGetMemory = function(Size: NativeInt): Pointer; cdecl;
var
  TrampolineGetMemory: TTrampolineGetMemory = nil;
```